# Returning Mono from @Around method of aspect

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-aop, spring-webflux

I am using Spring AOP for profiling method execution time. My methods uses Spring WebFlux and returns a Mono of various types viz. `Map`, `List` , custom objects of Java classes. But `jointPoint.proceed()` in `@Around` advice returns object. How can I return the same Mono from `doAround` method.
The method whose execution time I want to know is as follows :

```
public Mono<Map<Integer, Car>> getCarObject(List<Integer> cardIds) {

    if (cardIds == null || cardIds.isEmpty()) {
        return Mono.fromCallable(() -> new HashMap<>());
    } 

    return Mono.fromCallable(() -> listingClient.getCarObject(carIds).getData());
}
```

My aspect class is as follows :

```
@Aspect
@Configuration
public class Demo  {

private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

@Pointcut("execution(* com.Car.*.mediators.*.*(..))")
public void feignClientPointcut() {

}
@Around("feignClientPointcut()")
public void doAround(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {

        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

        Object object = joinPoint.proceed();  
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();

        long time = end - start;
        logger.error("Around Method Name = {}",joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
        logger.error("Around time :{}",time);


}
}
```

How can I return the same Mono from `doAround` method. Because on returning  `Mono<object>` the caller function of method throws an error as it expects a `Map` not a object ?

Comment: Can you share the exception stack trace?